# Exporting a class results in "TypeError: ... is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have node.js app in which I have a `class.js` module in which

```
var MyClass = module.exports.MyClass = function MyClass(){}

Object.defineProperty(MyClass, 'MyArray', ['value1','value2']);

MyClass.prototype.MyFunction = function(){
    //---
}
```

Then I `require` it in my main `app.js`

```
var MyClass = require('./class.js');

var myInstance = new MyClass(); // TypeError: object is not a function
```

but it throws that error when I try to instantiate it with `new`. What am I doing wrong here? I've tried a lot of alterations but none works, but I do know that it(or something close to it) used to work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var MyClass = require('./class.js').MyClass;
```

You have to assign to `MyClass` the `MyClass` member which you set on the `exports` object. Otherwise you are invoking `new` with the module instance returned by `require`.

Otherwise you could export like this:

```
var MyClass = module.exports = exports = function MyClass(){}
```

and keep your `require` statement as is. In this case you are exporting one and *only* one function from your module. (Technically, you don't need to assign to `exports` in the line above. However, if you don't then `exports` [ceases to be an alias](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_alias) of `module.exports`. I prefer to keep them in sync.)